# Count number of rows use mysql like condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contain list of book. I want to count the number of row with "mysql php" in it.

If I use regular like (use the code below), it only count the row with 'mysql php'.

```
SELECT 'mysql php' as searched_word, 
        count(case when book_list like '%mysql php%' then 1 else 0 end) AS number_of_occurrences
FROM book_list
```

What I want is, it also count the row with "php mysql" value, but I don't have idea how to do it.

This is the table:

```
+------------------------+
| book_list              |
+------------------------+
| mysql php for dummies  |
+------------------------+
| learn php mysql        |
+------------------------+
| mysql php for students |
+------------------------+
| mysql database         |
+------------------------+
```

my expected result:

```
+---------------+-----------------------+
| searched_word | number_of_occurrences |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| mysql php     | 3                     |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: It seems you want to use "full text search".

Comment: Does 'php mysql' substring (sample row 2) matches your criteria, or the order of searched tokens must be taken into account?

Comment: Where is the search term coming from? Do you run the code from an app, like a web search app? If so, that means user can type whatever, however..

Comment: Use `SUM` not `count` in this case

Comment: I try full text searching, but it count all the book that containt "mysql and php", not only "mysql php" or "php mysql" @TheImpaler

Comment: Yes, it match my criteria. So, it will count book with "mysql php" or "php mysql" in it @Akina

Comment: I run it on my web app. But it's not a kind of search box. I need the result to implement to another code @tcadidot0

Comment: If so then specify your MySQL server precise version.

Comment: You appear to want a SUM, not a COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

Make the condition an `or`, and use `sum()` (not `count()`):

```
select
    'mysql php' as searched_word, 
    sum(book_list like '%mysql php%' or book_list like '%php mysql%') AS number_of_occurrences
from book_list
```

Note the way MySQL allows briefer code to count conditions, because 'true'  is '1' and 'false' is '0'.

---

If you wanted to count rows that had *both* terms somewhere, eg `"learn php and mysql"`, use this:

```
sum(book_list like '%php%' and book_list like '%mysql%')
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
-- parse searching criteria to separate tokens (delimiter - space), remove duplicates
cte1 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT token
FROM JSON_TABLE( CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@criteria, ' ', '","'), '"]'),
                       "$[*]" COLUMNS( token VARCHAR(254) PATH "$" )
                ) AS jsontable
),
-- select books which' title contains ALL tokens as complete words
-- words delimiter - space 
-- commas, dots and another punctuation is NOT removed
cte2 AS (
SELECT book_list.book_list 
FROM book_list
JOIN cte1 ON LOCATE(cte1.token, REPLACE(book_list.book_list, ' ', CHAR(0)))
GROUP BY book_list.book_list
HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM cte1 )
)
-- count the amount of matched titles
SELECT @criteria searched_word, COUNT(*) number_of_occurrences
FROM cte2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3f3949c0ba3c36c3e18c10bf71e50a5)

PS. Needed MySQL 8.0.4 or newer.